# failure to select a file when uploading a file with html file type input on iOS11 and Cordova

Tags: html, ios, cordova, input, file-upload

A Cordova project, With `<input type="file">`, click the "choose a file" button to select a file, after return, no changes, still with "no file selected"

what I want is the selected file name here, on iOS, even a preview picture here.

1. this code works well on Android device
2. this code works well on iphone 6S device with iOS 9
3. this code not work on iphone X device with iOS 11.2
4. with this code, iphone 6S and iphoneX simulators, the wrong result: "no changes, still with "no file selected"
5. no matter what cases, the log with error message like: "PhotoPicker discovery error: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}", but as #2, seems this message is not the reason for this issue
6. but a demo cordova code works well on iphone X device with iOS 11.2
7. also added NSCameraUsageDescription, NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription in Cordova's config.xml
8. use UIWebview, instead of WKWebview
9. go through or try almost all Q&A on StackOverflow or other websites, no lucky.

the simplest code is :

```
<input type="file">
```

Actual results: no changes, still with "no file selected" following the file button

Expected: the selected file name following the file button

updated:
so far, seems the dojotoolkit(we use dojox/mobile) makes the differents, when click the choose file button, popup the dialog to select file, then code breaks at dojo/on's touch/touch-can-modify-event-delegate lines, after choose one file, the preview pic is following the file button.